# Post.get in django and html form method

Tags: python, html, django

So i tried this code for a web app and it give me this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plnWp.png)

```
def speedup(request):
m1 = int(request.POST.get['mi1',False])
m3 = int(request.POST.get['mi3',False])
m5 = int(request.POST.get['mi5',False])
m10= int(request.POST.get['mi10',False])
m15= int(request.POST.get['mi15',False])
m30= int(request.POST.get['mi30',False])

# result calculation

return render(request,'Speed Result.html',{"days":T})
```

html

```
<form action= "{%url 'sp'%}" method="POST" >
```

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plnWp.png)

Comment: What do you mean by post.get[] ?

Comment: request.POST.get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
m1 = int(request.POST.get('mi1'))
m3 = int(request.POST.get('mi3'))
m5 = int(request.POST.get('mi5'))
m10= int(request.POST.get('mi10'))
m15= int(request.POST.get('mi15'))
m30= int(request.POST.get('mi30'))
```

OR

```
m1 = int(request.POST['mi1'])
m3 = int(request.POST['mi3'])
m5 = int(request.POST['mi5'])
m10= int(request.POST['mi10'])
m15= int(request.POST['mi15'])
m30= int(request.POST[('mi30'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use those rounded brackets () instead of square brackets []

Comment: did not work . i

Comment: Do you get same error?

Comment: return render(request,'Speed Result.html',{"days":T})

Comment: it directly went to speed result.html without performing any calculations or taking inputs

Comment: Your problem description isn't clear. Please update your question to clarify whole problem.

Comment: did , sorry new to stackoverflow.